# DataTable inside Dialog results in wrong width

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, dialog, modal-dialog

I want to show a `p:dataTable` inside a modal `p:dialog` (entries which need to be deleted).
When I do something similar like the attached example, the dialog is shown with 100% width. How can I avoid this? Without `p:datatable`, the dialog is rendered according to its content.

Minimal example:

```
<p:dialog header="Example" widgetVar="exampleDlg" closable="true" 
          resizable="false" appendTo="@(body)" modal="true">
    <h:form id="exampleForm">
        <p:dataTable emptyMessage="Even an empty DataTale">
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

I'm on Primefaces 5.1 Snapshot, but with 5.0 it's the same. I tried afterdark, bootstrap and default theme and always the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have that datatable styled with some scalable/percentage width like `width: 100%;` so the dialog is taking all the space in order to represent the width of the datatable accordingly. So you have two options to fix it:

Give the dialog a width:

```
<p:dialog header="Example" widgetVar="exampleDlg" closable="true" 
                      resizable="false" appendTo="@(body)" modal="true" width="50%">
```

also

```
<p:dialog header="Example" widgetVar="exampleDlg" closable="true" 
                      resizable="false" appendTo="@(body)" modal="true" width="400">
```

Or give the datatable a fixed width:

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="Even an empty DataTale" style="width: 300px;">
```

Comment: You´re right, the column for selection does have a width of 16px, but all other elements aren´t styled. And the minimal example   behaves the same. I used your first hint and its okay ... I need to look whats happen if the content will be larger. I thought not setting any width and relying on the default behavior ("width: auto") will be enough :( Thx so far :)

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way (if not the best) to solve your problem is by using [CSS Media Queries](http://www.templatemonster.com/blog/css-media-queries-for-all-devices-and-browsers-including-ie7-and-ie8/). You can "fit" your datatable just by using classes.

For example,

.xhtml

```
<p:dialog header="My Dialog Name" styleClass="my-dialog-class">
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable id="myTable">
            ....
        </p:dataTable>
    </form>
</p:dialog>
```

.css

```
@media(min-width: 320px) {
    .my-dialog-class {
        width: 318px !important;
    }   
}
@media(min-width: 360px) {
    .my-dialog-class {
        width: 358px !important;
    }
}
```

Here we are assuming between 320 and 360px our dialog will always have 318px.